# How to change text color depends on the text value using javascript for reactjs web applicatiion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

{data.status}

If data status value is Yes means, then it will be green color
If datastatus value is No means, then it will be red color
if datastatus value is other than yes or no ,It will not display content

I am new to reactjs.So please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can change the CSS class name with JavaScript and then assign different colors to those class names:

```
{
    <div className={data.status === "yes" ? "green" : "red"}>
      My color will change
    </div>
}
```

Then in your CSS file simply assign colors to those class names.

Answer (score 0):

Using ternaries, you can try `{data.status === "No"? "red" : data.status === "Yes"? "green": null }`. But since you are new to react, I'd suggest to create a function outside the component scope.
something like:

```js
   function getStatusText(status){
      if(status === "No"){
        return "RED"
      }else if(status === "Yes"){
        return "GREEN"
      }
      return null
   }
```

and in the component you can use it as `{getStatusText(data.status)}`

Comment: 'getStatusTextColor' failed compiled

Comment: <span class="text-danger" >{getStatusTextColor(data.status)}</span>

Comment: @umaraja Can you share the failed compile message you received? I see no reason why this shouldn't work.